# Excel VBA, lastCol from Row2 to lastRow and concatenate formula

Tags: excel, vba

There's 2 thing I am stuck with

1. I am trying to apply a formula to the last Column from Row 2 to the last row
2. Formula: concat rows based on another sheet

```
Option Explicit

Sub concat()

Dim lastCol As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Range(Cells(2, lastCol) & lastRow) = Application.WorksheetFunction.concat(application.WorksheetFunction.Index(cells(2,match(worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K3").value,worksheets("Sheet1").rows(1)), application.WorksheetFunction.Index(cells(2,match(worksheets("Sheet2").Range("L3").value,worksheets("Sheet1").rows(1)))
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this code and replace with your formula

```
Option Explicit

Sub concat()
Dim aRng As Range
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

Set aRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
lastRow = aRng.Cells(1, 1).Row + aRng.Rows.Count - 1
lastCol = aRng.Cells(1, 1).Column + aRng.Columns.Count - 1

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Write the formula in cell(2,lastCol), just below Headers
    .Cells(2, lastCol).Formula = "=F2 + 65"  'put your formula in the brackets
    
    'now autofill to end (or copy/paste formula)
    .Cells(2, lastCol).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(Cells(2, lastCol), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: if we are talking about huge workbooks then improve performance with application.calculation and application.screenUpdating as needed